# Exclusion pattern not working for vsts build

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to setup our CI environment using VSTS build but I need to exclude one project from the nuget packaging.  I'm using the Nuget pack task.  I'm setting the path to csproj field to 
`**\*.csproj;-:**\<name of proj>.csproj`

However, it seems to be excluding all projects and not packaging anything.  I've done some research and the exclusion takes priority over the inclusion, but even when I specify the exact location of the project to exclude it still excludes everything.  Remove the -: bit correctly builds everything so it's definitely something wrong with the exclusion.

Does anyone know if this is a bug (https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/4336 looks similar, but not the same). Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the negative pattern seems can't work.

There is an issue [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/4702) which I added a comment, you can follow up.

Comment: Marked as answer because my question was really is this a bug...which it looks like it is.